# Does a first generation iPod touch have the ability to download apps and use emojis?

Tags: ipod-touch

I am getting a 1st gen iPod touch for a friend and I was wondering if you can download like apps and games on it and if it has emojis? It would help to get an answer before I buy it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the App Store exists as that was introduced with iPhone OS 2.0, however most apps on the store do not support iPhone OS 3.1.3 (the last version available for the 1st generation iPod touch).

Emojis can be activated through ['emoji hack' apps](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2009/06/29/how-to-enable-emoji-icons-on-os-30/) on the App Store.

Comment: Thank you. I asked someone and they said that on all iPod's you can go to the settings and get the emojis. She said she wanted emojis so I wanted to make sure!

Comment: @camohope47 Only newer versions of iOS have the emoji keyboard available in Settings by default.

Comment: I have another question. Sorry. But does the first generation have an alarm?

Answer (score 0):

You can download apps for it, but it is now so old that it will only run iOS 3.1.3 so many newer apps & games will be unlikely to be supported.

Emoji I think was added to the built-in font around iOS 5, so they will be unavailable.

See http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipod/specs/ipod-touch-specs.html for more details

Comment: Okay thank you. I was wondering because my friend said her kid wanted an iPod for her birthday and she is only like 10.